# Redis - Check if key exists using predis

Tags: php, redis, predis

Using `predis` is it possible to check if a key exists?

My `users` data is stored as follows:

```
public function createUser($email, $password, $username)
{
    return $this->predis->hMset("user:{$username}", [
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password,
        'username' => $username
    ]);
}
```

Now, when I check to see if a user exists I do the following:

```
public function checkUserExists($username)
{
    return $this->predis->hExists("user:{$username}", 'username');
}
```

Is it possible to check if the user exists without having to check if the key exists? For example by just checking `user:{$username}`?

Comment: You can only check if the `key` exists and not the `value`. You can't check for `value` without a `key`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Since your key is essentially just the user name, you can just see if the key exists. You can use Redis' `EXISTS` for this:

```
public function checkUserExists($username)
{
    return $this->predis->exists("user:{$username}");
}
```

The speed difference between the two will be very, very small, but using `exists` will make your code a bit cleaner.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up solving my problem a different way as I also needed to check if both email, and username, already exist (separately). I used a set for emails, and a set for username and then used exists to check Thanks.